# How to organize properly the transition back in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I load data from `URL`, parsing it, and put in `TableView`. When user push on some row - initializing method in which pass element's ID and again load data from `URL`, parsing and reloading `TableView`. This continues until user saw last element, when he push on it - opens new `ViewController` (`DetailViewController` for example). It will be good if user can go back and see in reverse it all. With `DetailView` all clear - just organized data back with segue, and reload scene.
 But the my question is - How to make that when user push Back button on `Tableview`, `TableView reloading` in right reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

In this case navigationControl is your friend. Build different views for any click, then instantiate and call the pushViewController with navigationControl. The navigationControl will handle the back button it self.

Comment: problem is - I dont know how many views I'll need, because it can be very different: from 3 to 5,6,7 etc.

Comment: Okay so two ways here. first one you cache everything your user does easy way but cost a lot of memory. Second one stack the Id's in a Array when the user click on a row. When back button is hit, repopulate with the stacked id's.

Comment: the second way is the best, fast, few memory costs, and very clean.